# including stb_image to an OpenGL Project with CMake

Tags: opengl, cmake, texture2d

i need to code a little game with OpenGL for a Student Project. I also have to use CMake for this project. I included the stb_image.c for importing textures.

I included the following lines to my CMakeList.txt

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../extern/stb_image)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../extern/stb_image)
```

and included the stb_image.h to my project file. The Code compiles without errors. Now I tried to import a texture to my project with the following code.

```
#include "stb_image.h"
int x, y, n;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("testTexture.png" , &x, &y, &n, 0);
```

if i try to compile the project with the "make" command I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable /Users/.../Documents/.../.../.../binaries/basic-texturing
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_stbi_load", referenced from:
      loadObjectsAndTextures() in inits.cc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/.../Documents/.../.../.../binaries/basic-texturing] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/basic-texturing.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

inits.cc is the project file and loadObjectsAndTextures() is the method that calls stbi_load().

I dont realy know what crashs here. Did I link the file wrong with CMake, is my function call wrong or is it something I dont even see here. Could you give me any advice where I can start to solve this problem? I tried several hours to read through tutorials for CMake and the [Documentation](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c) for stb_image. The texture is located in the same directory of my project file and also in the same directory as the stb_image.c.

Answer (score 5):

Hey there you just need to add this above the include.

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot...After it works, I read the stb_image.h header file. Right at the top there is the direction to define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION  #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION before you include this file in *one* C or C++ file to create the implementation.
   // i.e. it should look like this:
   #include ...
   #include ...
   #include ...
   #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
   #include "stb_image.h"

Answer (score -2):

Looks to me like you're trying to link a version of stb_image that wasn't compiled for 64 bit systems. Are you sure you're using the proper library file for your system?